# Bad Function Call _m5.event.simulate(*args, **kwargs) When Running Full System Benchmarks

Tags: gem5

It takes nearly three hours for the simulator to get pass the initialization point when I try to run a PARSEC benchmark in full system mode, only to be met with the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "build/X86/python/m5/main.py", line 457, in main
      exec(filecode, scope)
   File "configs/example/fs.py", line 396, in <module>
      Simulation.run(options, root, test_sys, FutureClass)
   File "configs/common/Simulation.py", line 726, in run
      exit_event = benchCheckpoints(options, maxtick, cptdir)
   File "configs/common/Simulation.py", line 269, in benchCheckpoints
      exit_event = m5.simulate(maxtick - m5.curTick())
   File "build/X86/python/m5/simulate.py", line 180, in simulate
      return _m5.event.simulate(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: bad_function_call
```

I don't even know where to begin solving this problem. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Mailing list message: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg17041.html Are you running parsec with the `parsecmgmt` Bash script? That is horrendously slow in gem5, you have to run them on X86 host first and extract the final executable run command as shown at: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#parsec-benchmark-without-parsecmgmt Then with this faster test loop, start debugging it further with GDB / `std::cout` on gem5 source code to find what is throwing that.